# C# and Telerik: Identifying the appropriate user control on pop up close

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, telerik

I have to reuse the user controls I'm creating multiple times on a single page. This user control has a listbox and a button. On clicking the button, a radwindow opens and will send some value back to the caller on close. I have to identify the appropriate user control when the pop-up closes and populate the listbox with the value returned.

I'm running into two issues here. One is the question posted, how do I identify calling user control from the pop-up. Second, is something wrong on my ajaxrequest code? Even if I hardcode values, the listbox does not get populated.

Parent.aspx

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadScriptManager>

<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager" runat="server">    
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>

 <telerik:radwindowmanager id="RadWindowManager1" reloadonshow="true" showcontentduringload="false" runat="server" behavior="Default" initialbehavior="None" ></telerik:radwindowmanager>

    <div>
         <uc:Control ID="Ctrl1" runat="server"></uc:Control >
         <uc:Control ID="Ctrl2" runat="server"></uc:Control >
         <uc:Control ID="Ctrl3" runat="server"></uc:Control >
    </div>
```

UserControl.ascx

```
 <telerik:RadCodeBlock runat="server" ID="RadCodeBlock1">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function foo() {
                var oWnd = radOpen('PopUp.aspx', "Title");                
                oWnd.add_close(OnClientClose);
                return false;
            }

            function OnClientClose(oWnd) {
                var ajaxManager = $find("<%= RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(Page).ClientID %>");

                ajaxManager.ajaxRequest('Processed return value'); 
                return false;
           }
</script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>

<telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy ID="AjaxManagerProxy1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="ListBox">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="ListBox" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox" Width="100px" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="AddButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="return foo(); return false;" Text="Add" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

UserControl.ascx.cs

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var manager = RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(Page);

            manager.AjaxRequest += new RadAjaxControl.AjaxRequestDelegate(RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest);
        }

        protected void RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Argument)) 
            {
                ListBox.Items.Add(new RadListBoxItem(e.Argument)); //This code runs without error but does not populate the list box. I even tried to harcode the control ID against which this code should run. The code ran only for the required control but listbox was not populated.
            }
        }
```

Also, all the 3 user controls get executed on the postback. Is there a way to prevent it? It's been a while since I have dealt with user controls and telerik, so if I missed out on any crucial detail in the sample above, please let me know.

I do have to use telerik but not necessarily ajaxrequest. I tried some javascript code from telerik demos to populate the listbox but that didn't work either.

Any help/clues/directions appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To know which control fired - consider using flags (e.g., hidden field, or a custom field in the client-side object of the RadWindow).

On AJAX settings - since you invoke an AJAX request through the manager, you need an AJAX setting where the manager updates the conrtols you need. Perhaps you need to create the needed AJAX settings programmatically: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-add-ajaxsettings-programmatically.html

On loading all the user controls after a postback - they should, else they will be lost. This is the way ASP operates. It is nothing specific to Telerik.

Comment: I was able to get the first control updated using AjaxSettings.
Parent page looks like

<AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadAjaxManager">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="ctrl1" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="ctrl2" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="ctrl3" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>



But only the first control gets updated. Any suggestions what I could be missing?

Comment: The IDs in the snippet have a capital "C" but the AJAX settings do not. Also, the ID of the RadAjaxManager should not match its class name, change it to RadAjaxManager1 or something similar.